# How can I detect if a polygon(drawn in canvas) is clicked by me？

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to DIY a canvas animation library,after I add all kinds of shape, I need to add events to them for interaction.

> NOTICE  I know the API  isPointInPath(),while it can run well in browser but I want to do it in WeiXin App where there is no `isPointInPath`

here are all my shapes

- circle
- rect
- polygon

it's easy to detect if I clicked the circle and rect.

- for **circle**,say (x',y') is the circle's center coordinate,(x,y) is my mouse's 
  coordinate
  if   `(x - x')^2+(y - y')^2 <=r^2`,we can think that we clicked the circle.
- for **rect**,say (x',y') is the rect's coordinate,w and h are it's width and height,(x,y) is my mouse's (x,y) is my mouse's coordinate,
  if `0<(x - x')<w&&0<(y - y')<h`,we can think that we clicked the rect.

while if I follow rect's detecting algorithm to detect polygon,it will be too hard and too inefficiency.

if there anyone can tell me how to solve that？

> my polygon core code

```js
   getPoints: function () {
            var points = [],
                angle = this.startAngle || 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.sides; ++i) {
                points.push(new Point(this.x + this.radius * Math.sin(angle), this.y - this.radius * Math.cos(angle)));
                angle += 2 * Math.PI / this.sides;
            }
            return points;
        },
  createPath: function (context) {
       
        var points = this.getPoints();

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
        for (var i = 1; i < this.sides; ++i) {
            context.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
        }
        context.closePath();
    },
```

Comment: why don;t you use 3rd party library to handle canvas , it will make your life a lot easier. best is "fabricjs" . anyway if you want to do it yourself, check this link http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1903884&seqNum=6

Comment: for work ,I will use the 3rd party library,while this time I just want to DIY a library and learn more.

Comment: I find a way to solve it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon